# Terraform docker provider python "container exited immediately"

Tags: python, docker, terraform

I am trying to build a python docker image with the following code:

```
resource "docker_image" "python_img" {
  name = "python:3.11.2"
  keep_locally = true
}

resource "docker_container" "python" {
  image = docker_image.python_img.image_id
  name = "python"
}
```

I always get the following error

```
╷
│ Error: container exited immediately
│ 
│   with docker_container.python,
│   on main.tf line 85, in resource "docker_container" "python":
│   85: resource "docker_container" "python" {
│ 
╵
```

It only do this with python regardless of the tag. Other images I tried works fine.

Version info:

```
Terraform v1.3.9
on darwin_amd64
+ provider registry.terraform.io/kreuzwerker/docker v3.0.1
```

How can I troubleshoot this ?

Comment: You wouldn't normally just run an unmodified `python` container, especially through a noninteractive deploy system like Terraform.  Do you have a derived image containing your application that you mean to run instead?

Comment: No, so I need to build a derived image to get a workaround ? Why should I avoid to run an unmodified `python` container ?

Comment: So say you deploy a container that has a Python interpreter, but no actual code or running application in it.  What now?  How would you make calls to it?

Comment: I see because there is no code running in it, it stops immediately. If I import my code it should work ? I plan to make calls to it by integrating it in a private network so it can interact with other containers.

Comment: The Docker [Build your Python image](https://docs.docker.com/language/python/build-images/) might be a good starting point; once you've built your image with your application and pushed it into a repository, _then_ connect it to Terraform.

Answer (score 0):

It don't work because there is no code running on the container. It will exit automatically after the code is ended.